# Python : Replace a column in a dataframe by datetime values

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy, netcdf

I'm trying to replace a column an array of 4 columns by datetime values that I treated. The problem is that it's difficult to keep the same form between the different formats of dataframe, array,....

```
dataw = ds.variables["pr"][:]
dataw = np.array(dataw[:,0,0])
lat = ds.variables["lat"][:]
long = ds.variables["lon"][:]
time = ds.variables["time"][:]

time = pd.to_datetime(ds.variables["time"][:],origin=pd.Timestamp('1850-01-01'),unit='D')
#np.datetime64(ds.variables["time"][:],'D')
x2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(dataw),4), float))
x = np.zeros((len(dataw),4), float)


x[:,0] = time
x[:,1] = long
x[:,2] = lat[:]
x[:,3] = dataw[:]*86400


x=pd.DataFrame(x)
x[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(time,origin=pd.Timestamp('1850-01-01'),unit='D')
```

If I put directly the dates transformed in the array, the result is like: 1.32542e+18

I tried

```
time = ds.variables["time"][:]
```

and include it in the array, and then use

```
x[:,0]=pd.to_datetime(x[:,0],origin=pd.Timestamp('1850-01-01'),unit='D')
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

I tried also directly put:

```
time=pd.to_datetime(time,origin=pd.Timestamp('1850-01-01'),unit='D')
x[:,0] = time[:]
```

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Comment: You may find xarray to be a useful tool for this workflow. Something like `xarray.open_dataset('file.nc').to_pandas()` should give you the dataframe you are trying to construct.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
        import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    dataw = ds.variables["pr"][:]
    dataw = np.array(dataw[:, 0, 0])
    lat = ds.variables["lat"][:]
    long = ds.variables["lon"][:]
    time = ds.variables["time"][:]
    
    time = np.datetime64(time, 'D')
x = np.zeros((len(dataw), 4), dtype='datetime64[D]')
    x[:, 0] = time
    x[:, 1] = long
    x[:, 2] = lat
    x[:, 3] = dataw * 86400
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["Time", "Longitude", "Latitude", "Data"])
```

Comment: The problem in this case is that I lose the datetime format and I get values as "1.32542e+18"

Comment: The reason for the display of the date as "1.32542e+18" is because the numpy array x is of type float, and datetime objects are not supported by the float type. To resolve this issue, you can convert the entire x array to a numpy datetime64 type before creating the DataFrame:

Comment: ok but I don't get how to merge the arrays with the two different formats (datetime and float) after converting in dataframe, I tried pd.concat and pd.merge  but I get this error: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Xarray makes the netcdf->pandas workflow quite straightforward:

```py
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('file.nc', engine='netcdf4')
df = ds.to_pandas()
```

Presuming your time variable is using cf-conventions, Xarray will automatically decode it into datetime objects.